# An example of a retract that is not a deformation retract.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

I was told that the retraction of $S^2$ into a point is a retract but not a deformation retract , could someone explain this to me please?

If I understood this wrongly, could someone give me an example of a retract that is not a deformation retract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any point $p\in S^2$ is a retract of $S^2$, because the constant map $f:S^2\to\{p\}$ given by $f(x)=p$ is continuous and fixes $p$.

Nonetheless, no point is a deformation retract of $S^2$, because that would mean $S^2$ would be contractible, and [that is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405191/the-sphere-s2-is-not-contractible).

Intuitively, you can map $S^2$ to $p$ continuously (namely, by sending all $S^2$ to $p$), but you cannot continuously *shrink* the sphere to a point while staying in the sphere itself: there is always a hole inside.

Comment: So the condition $i \circ r \sim id_X$ relative to A is not satisfied, right?

Comment: What is my X and A again in this case please ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882046/difference-between-the-sphere-and-rp2-in-the-generators-and-relations-of-pi-1/4882050#4882050  can you please take a look at this question and explain it the same way you explained here (by description I mean)?

Comment: @Intuition I guess with $X$ you mean the whole space and $A$ the retract. In this case, we would have $X=S^2$ and $A=\{p\}$. The condition you mention is precisely what isn't satisfied: the identity map on $S^2$ is not homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: @Intuition I don't get what you mean with that last comment.

Comment: I mean can you just tell me according to the pictures why there can not be a generator for $S^2$ in the other question?

Comment: Any closed path on $S^2$ can be continuosly reduced to a point, so the fundamental group of $S^2$ is trivial, there is no generator for it.

Comment: Do you have any justification for my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4881960/the-free-product-of-two-presentations-is-isomorphic-to-a-third-presentation-usin/4882083?noredire  (by the definition of UP I am writing there)? You can write a second answer there if you like

Comment: @Intuition If you still have doubts of questions you asked, I would suggest you ask the people that answered you /put a bounty on the question.

Comment: I think the author mentioned that she knows the answer only with her universal property, which is not what I wanted initially and bounties allowed only after two days and I want to know the solution sooner than this as I already tried it and failed to come up with a solution including the relations ad I mentioned.

Comment: Very mild comment, but I think a constant map on $S^1$ is slightly more attractive than on $S^2$ for the sole reason that it's simpler to convince oneself that $S^1$ is not simply connected.